# Quartz. JobStoreTX. The trigger is fired by two nodes simultaneously

Tags: java, quartz-scheduler

I have two nodes with the same schedulers of Quartz. The JobStore have the only trigger of the job which executes every 5 seconds and it takes one second to process the job.

When I the one node is up, everything is OK. When the 2nd node initializes its Quartz scheduler it changes the status of the ACQUIRED (by the 1st node) trigger to WAITING and then "picks it up" to execute (status then changed to ACQUIRED again).

So then **the job is executed by both nodes at the same time once**, then the only node continues to execute the job (which is expected behavior).
How to implement proper beavior for the whole cluster? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was resolved with specifying distinct values to property "**org.quartz.scheduler.instanceId**" (value "AUTO" can be used as well).

It had default "NON_CLUSTERED" value, so after initializing the second node, Quartz thought that it was re-initializing of failed node so it has released all jobs that were associated with the node to re-acquire them.